# Trying to add carousel to webpage without redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When I try to add this code to my webpage, whenever I click on the left or right arrow, it tries to redirect to "#carousel-example-generic", is there a way to do this without leaving my current web page?

Heres the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="http://www.cssscript.com/wp-includes/css/sticky.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Slideshow Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <img src="/temp/0.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption" style="text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="/temp/1.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Caption Text</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="/temp/2.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Caption Text</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the `href` from your links? Not sure what slider function you are using so can't really say if you need it or not.

Comment: $('.carousel-control').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }); you need something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to KJ Price's answer, you could do this (I assume you're using jQuery since you're clearly using Bootstrap):

```
$('.carousel-control').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

That way you can still keep the a tag, but the links won't trigger the new page load.

Comment: Thank you, I added this to my code and It fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove `href="#carousel-example-generic"` from your `<a>`. You may lose your "hand" when hovering though. So you may want to add `href="javascript:void(0);"` instead.

As so:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Use the css property *cursor: pointer* on the element you want the hand to return to.

Answer (score 0):

replace the `<a>` tag `href` links with hash like:

```
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
 </a>

 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

Or simply remove `href` from the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

It's not a redirect, but an anchor to focus your carousel. It should scroll to `<div id="carousel-example-generic" ...`.

Remove `href="javascript:void(0);"` and add `style="cursor:pointer"`